# How to make an application trusted?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Or in another way of understanding how to bypass the firewall of Windows in VB.NET?

Comment: What kind of research did you already do? What did google find out?

Comment: Bypassing any firewall does not sound very secure. Why do you need to?  Are you just wanting to have your program prompt the user to allow? Do you just want to pragmatically add a rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this guide to accessing the Windows Firewall API via managed code. This will allow you to open and close ports automatically from withing your program, is that what you are looking for?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/08/21/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c.aspx

It specifically gives this example to adding a program to the trusted programs list.

```
INetFwAuthorizedApplications applications; 
INetFwAuthorizedApplication application;
application.Name = “Internet Explorer”;/*set the name of the application */
application.ProcessImageFileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" /* set this property to the location of the executable file of the application*/
application.Enabled =  true; //enable it
/*now add this application to AuthorizedApplications collection */
Type NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", false); 
INetFwMgr mgr = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType); 
applications = (INetFwAuthorizedApplications)mgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications;
applications.Add(application);
```

**Edit Based on Comments**
Based on comments it looks like what you really want to look at is Code Signing.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing

This usually means buying a certificate (kind of like SSL) and applying it to your compiled application.  This is not the same as .NET's signing that is part of giving an assembly a strong name, it's something different.

Comment: no, i mean when you start the program on another computer the firewall blocks it and says that you're starting a program from an unauthorized publisher are you sure you want to do that and then you click yes or no