# How do I make my application trusted?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, publish

I am currently trying to publish an application I have created on VS2010, with C#. The most intrusive thing my program does is create a file and perform file IO. If I try to run the .exe file after the program is published on the laptop I have created it on, it works fine. But if I take the .exe folder to another computer, it keeps saying that my app may put the PC at risk. Is this normal? If it isn't, what steps can I take to make my app trusted?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your app, this is windows flagging all files downloaded from the internet as untrusted at first until you mark them as trusted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an application trusted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853057/how-to-make-an-application-trusted)

Comment: Right click the exe, select properties and press the "unblock" button.

Comment: So this means every user that downloads the file needs to unblock it? Damn...

Comment: Either that or create a proper installer for it.

Comment: No. The proper way to make it trusted is to sign it with a code signing certificate issued by a certified vendor like Verisign, as mentioned in the article linked above. It has nothing to do with needing to "unlock" it; @DavidG is wrong.